# How can I access a privately declared property through inheritance in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't understand why I can't access self.cardButtons in the child class SetCardCardgameViewController. The parent is CardgameViewController.

CardgameViewController.h:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Deck.h"

@interface CardgameViewController : UIViewController
- (void) updateUI;

//  protected
//  for subclasses

- (Deck *)createDeck;

// must be overriden in SetCardGameViewController as contents is not to be used for    instance
- (NSAttributedString *)titleForCard: (Card *)card;
- (UIImage *)backgroundImageforCard: (Card *)card;

@end
```

CardgameViewController.m

```
#import "CardgameViewController.h"
//#import "PlayingCardDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

@interface CardgameViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *matchMode;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *historySlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *historyOverview;

@end
```

SetCardCardgameViewController.h

```
#import "CardgameViewController.h"

@interface SetCardCardgameViewController : CardgameViewController

@end
```

SetCardCardgameViewController.m

```
#import "SetCardCardgameViewController.h"
#import "SetCardDeck.h"
#import "SetCard.h"

@interface SetCardCardgameViewController ()

@end

@implementation SetCardCardgameViewController

- (void)updateUI
{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {

}

}
```

this last self.cardButtons isn't recognized. But cardButtons is a property of the parent class. Why isn't it recognized? I agree it's privately declared but as SetCardCardgameViewController is a child of CardgameViewController, I thought I could access all its properties and methods. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The code in the m file is never seen by your subclass. You need to put the values in the header instead.

Comment: So I must delete it in .m, put it in .h and reconnect the storyboard elements to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaking private scoping for protected.

Semantically, there is no such thing as private or protected scoping due to the dynamic nature of Objective-C. You can emulate private scope the way you've done so above; however, methods or properties declared inside the .m file cannot be seen by its subclasses. Putting them in your header file makes them public and is usually the most common route to take. If you absolutely must make these methods/properties protected, you can add that interface to a separate header file and then import them in your subclasses, as such:

CardgameViewController_Internal.h

```
@interface CardgameViewController (Private)

@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *matchMode;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *historySlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *historyOverview;

@end
```

And then in SetCardCardgameViewController.m:

```
#import "SetCardCardgameViewController.h"
#import "SetCardDeck.h"
#import "SetCard.h"
#import "CardgameViewController_Internal.h"

@implementation SetCardCardgameViewController

- (void)updateUI
{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) { 

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Why is private still used then as one mostly wants to subclass a class?

Comment: The generally practiced rule is to encapsulate whatever you can as much as you can, unless you absolutely need it exposed. Objective-C has no practical way of emulating protected scope, but you should attempt to keep things as private as possible. Most subclass derivations I feel come based off the iOS SDK, and those methods/properties are obviously public for a reason.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I've learned something today! Did strike me a bit odd, but now I know if I want to use property in a subclass I'd better put property in a .h. This .h can be public of private. If it's private I must import it.

Comment: Awesome! If this answer helped you, please make sure you mark it as solved.

Comment: There should be a checkmark icon next to the up and down arrows. Just click that to mark it solved.

Comment: only a star, a zero, up & down arrow

Comment: Next to my answer, not your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly access any properties that are not declared in the header file because you do not import any symbols from the .m file, so the compiler does not know that they exist.

The properties still *exist* in your child class though, so something like this:

```
for (UIButton *cardButton in (NSArray*)[self valueForKey:@"cardButtons"])
```

*would* work without having to expose the property in your header file.

If you want strongly-typed properties (as you should), you can move your category (`@interface CardgameViewController ()`) to a separate header for private variables (something like `CardgameViewController+Private.h`), instead of declaring it in the .m file. Then you would import this private header in both the base class and the subclass.

Comment: Isn't this the same as writing (NsArray *)self.cardButtons?

Comment: Yes, but `self.cardButtons` is not accessible directly - which is the problem you're having

Comment: thanks very much. I remember vaguely from the book of Kochan that there was a difference between the dot notation and the [] notation. Don't remember what no more though.